# Problem related to continuous complex mapping.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

We are given with a map $g:\bar D\to \Bbb C $, which is continuous on $\bar D$ and analytic on $D$. Where $D$ is a ***bounded domain*** and $\bar D=D\cup\partial D$.

1) I want to show that: $\partial(g(D))\subseteq g(\partial D).$

And further, I need two examples:

a) First, to show that the above inclusion can be strict, that is: $\partial(g(D))\not= g(\partial D).$

b) Second example, I need to show that conclusion in (1) is not true if $D$ is  not bounded.

So basically we have to show that the boundary of the open set $g(D)$ is contained in image of boundary of $D$ (and sometimes strictly contained). I think that we will use open mapping theorem. But how this theorem will help us here that is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know by the open mapping theorem that $g(D)$ is open.  (I am assuming $g$ is non-constant.)  But you also know $\bar D$ is compact (closed and bounded), so $g(\bar D)$ is also compact, and hence closed.  Hence the closure of $g(D)$ is contained in $g(\bar D)$.  You should be able to argue at this point that $\partial(g(D)) = g(\bar D) \setminus g(D)$.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, So is that assumption necessary- $g$ is non-constant. Actually its not given.

Comment: I understand the rest except last line. Where you said, "You should be able to argue at this point that $\partial(g(D)) = g(\bar D) \setminus g(D)$."

Comment: So far we have proved that $\overline{g(D)}\subset g(\overline D)$ 

i.e. $g(D)\cup\partial (g(D))\subset g(D\cup \partial D)$. 

Does it imply $\partial (g(D))=g(\overline D)-g(D)?$ This is what you claimed to be true. But its not clear to me. And how it will help us to show that $\partial(g(D))\subseteq g(\partial D)?$

Comment: Can I write $g(\overline D \setminus D)=g(\overline D)-g(D)$. And in the end, we need to show that boundary of open set $D$ is subset of image of its boundary. i.e $\partial (g(D))\subset g(\partial D)$. And equality is also possible.

Comment: @SaraTancredi If $g$ is constant, there is probably a separate (and trivial) proof - if it is true.

Comment: @SaraTancredi You need to show that $\overline{g(D)} = g(\bar D)$.  The $\subset$ part is proved.  The converse comes from: if $x \in \bar D$, then there exist $x_n \in D$ such that $x_n \to x$ - since $g$ is continuous $g(x_n) \to g(x)$

Comment: It is not true that $g(A \setminus B) = g(A) \setminus g(B)$ unless $g$ is a 1-1 function.  But it is true that $g(A) \setminus g(B) \subset g(A \setminus B)$.

Comment: Now its quite clear; $g(\overline D)\setminus g(D)\subseteq g(\partial D) $, together with $\overline {g(D)} = g(\overline D)$ implies $\partial g(D) \subseteq g(\partial D).$ Thank you so much.

Comment: In which case this inclusion can be strict? I think $\partial g(D) \subset g(\partial D)$, when $g$ maps $\partial D$ in to image set of $D$ (that is, inside set $g(D)$); since g is not one one. Am I right Stephen?

Comment: @SaraTancredi Yes.  But the trick is to find an example.  I have two suggestions: 1.  $D = \{z:1<|z|<2\}$; 2.  $D = B(-2,1) \cup B(2,1)$.  I know how to do (2).  I would be interested if you can find an example using (1).

Comment: I mean $\partial g(D) \not= g(\partial D).$ when $g$ sends $\partial D$ inside set $g(D)$). But I want an example to show it.

Comment: Okay Stephen let me work on it. thanks :)

Comment: Domain $D$ is okay. But how will we define such map $g?$ which is not one one. In other words we want to map boundary of this annulus inside $g(D)$. How will we define such map!
If $D$ is as in case (1) Can I define it like: 

$g(z)$=
\begin{cases}
z/2,  & \text{if $z\in D$} \\
-2, & \text{if $z\in \partial D$}  \\
\end{cases}

Comment: Your $g$ is not continuous on $\bar D$.

Comment: We have to move to chat.  I cannot see your last comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11578/discussion-between-stephen-montgomery-smith-and-sara-tancredi)

Comment: Oh I made a mistake there. If $D$ is the above annulus.
$g(z)$=
\begin{cases}
z/2,  & \text{if $z\in D$} \\
\frac 34 z, & \text{if $z\in \partial D$}  \\
\end{cases}
Its not one one and continuous. Right!

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen, As we discussed yesterday, If we take $g(z)= z^2$ and $D$ =\begin{cases}z, & \text{where 1<|z|<2} \\\end{cases}
Now, we want to prove that $g(\partial D)\not\subset \partial(g(D)) $. Therefore, we need to show that $\exists $ some $z\in g(\partial D)$ but $z \not\in \partial(g(D))$.

First, I want to talk about domain $D$ and its image by map $g$. Please check it:[image]

??

Comment: Actually I realized that the way to really do it was to consider $D = \{z:|z|<1\} \setminus (\text{first-quadrant})$, and then consider the map $g(z) = z^2$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith How does it prove $g(\partial D)\not\subset \partial(g(D)).$ What is the way to visualize it. Please explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: if we take domain, $D'=D(1,2) $ \ $(-1,0)$ (We are eliminating the interval $(-1,0)$). We get $g(D')= D$ and $\partial D'=\partial D\cup (-1,0)$. Now we are done. Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to assume the function $g$ to be bounded. If the image curve $f(\partial D)$ forms infinitely many loops everywhere, then $\partial f(D)\subsetneqq f(\partial D)$.

Comment: Will you elaborate it?

Comment: Sorry, It is my intuition. If you want to refer some resource, I recommend the paper "Cantor boundary behavior of analytic functions" writed by Xin-Han Dong&Ka-Sing Lau.